# Inserting multiple types into an SQLite database with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to create an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3 database from Python. I have a few types I'd like to insert into each record: A float, and then 3 groups of n floats, currently a tuple but could be an array or list.. I'm not well-enough versed in Python to understand all the differences. My problem is the INSERT statement.

```
DAS = 12345
lats = (42,43,44,45)
lons = (10,11,12,13)
times = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute( "create table foo(DAS LONG PRIMARY KEY,lats real(4),lons real(4), times real(9) )" )
```

I'm not sure what comes next. Something along the lines of:

```
cmd = 'INSERT into foo values (?,?,?,?), ..."
cursor.execute(cmd)
```

How should I best build the SQL insert command given this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `real(4)` does not mean an array/list/tuple of 4 reals; the 4 alters the 'real' type.  However, SQLite mostly ignores column types due to its manifest typing, but they can still affect [column affinity](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

You have a few options, such as storing the text representation (from repr) or using four columns, one for each.

You can modify this with various hooks provided by the Python's [SQLite library](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) to handle some of the transformation for you, but separate columns (with functions to localize and handle various statements, so you don't repeat yourself) is probably the easiest to work with if you need to search/etc. in SQL on each value.

If you do store a text representation, [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (or eval, under special conditions) will convert back into a Python object.

Comment: I don't have enough points to vote your comment up, but it appears everything getting its own column is the best way for now.

I do have large arrays that need to go into the DB, and I will only be searching on the primary key, so I will use text encoding at that point, unless you have some advice for storing arrays of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into foo values (?,?,?,?)", (val1, val2, val3, val4))
db.commit() # Autocommit is off by default (and rightfully so)!
```

Please note, that I am *not* using string formatting to inject actual data into the query, but instead make the library do this work for me. That way the data is quoted and escaped correctly.

EDIT: Obviously, considering your database schema, it doesn't work. It is impractical to attempt to store a collection-type value in a single field of a **sqlite** database. If I understand you correctly, you should just create a separate column for every value you are storing in the single row. That will be a lot of columns, sure, but that's the most natural way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get the following error with your suggestion:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute("insert into foo values (?,?,?,?)", (val1, val2, val3, val4))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Yup, it appears everything needs its own column.

Answer (score 0):

(A month later), two steps:
1. flatten e.g. DAS lats lons times to one long list, say 18 long
2. generate "Insert into tablename xx (?,?,... 18 question marks )" and execute that.

```
Test = 1

def flatten( *args ):
    """ 1, (2,3), [4,5] -> [1 2 3 4 5] """
    # 1 level only -- SO [python] [flatten] zzz
    all = []
    for a in args:
        all.extend( a if hasattr( a, "__iter__" )  else [a] )
     if Test:  print "test flatten:", all
    return all

def sqlinsert( db, tablename, *args ):
    flatargs = flatten( *args )  # one long list
    ncol = len(flatargs)
    qmarks = "?" + (ncol-1) * ",?"
    insert = "Insert into tablename %s values (%s)" % (tablename, qmarks)
    if Test:  print "test sqlinsert:", insert
    if db:
        db.execute( insert, flatargs )
        # db.executemany( insert, map( flatargs, rows ))
    return insert

#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sqlinsert( None, "Table", "hidiho", (4,5), [6] )
```